PyTorch mobile: Undefined method
I build a "*.pt" file using pyTorch mobile, this is my python code:
  def optimizeSave(model, model_folder):
    # Scripting the entire model
    scripted_module = torch.jit.script(model)
    scripted_module_optimized = 
    optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module,preserved_methods=["inference"])
    scripted_module_optimized._save_for_lite_interpreter(f"{model_folder}/inference.pt")

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return x

    @torch.jit.export
    def inference(self, x: str):
        # Dummy implementation for string processing, normally you'd do some tensor operations
        return f"Processed string: {x}"



model = MyModel()
model.eval()
optimizeSave(model, "models")
print("finished")

The "inference.pt" file has been successfully generated and loaded in Android. While the "forward" function can be called without any issues, attempting to call the "inference" function results in a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined method inference" error. Here is the relevant Android function and log:
   private void referenceModule() {
        String fileName="inference.pt";
        try {
            Module referenceModule =    LiteModuleLoader.load(assetFilePath(fileName));
// Prepare a dummy tensor input for the forward method
            Tensor inputTensor = Tensor.fromBlob(new float[10], new long[]{1, 10});
// Call the forward method
            IValue output = referenceModule .runMethod("forward", IValue.from(inputTensor));
           if(output != null)
             Log.i(TAG,output.toString());

            IValue result = referenceModule.runMethod("inference",IValue.from("I am from android"));
            Log.i(TAG,"@referenceModule result is: "+result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }

    }

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined method inference
    at org.pytorch.LiteNativePeer.runMethod(Native Method)
    at org.pytorch.Module.runMethod(Module.java:63)
    at com.example.pytorch_app.MainActivity.referenceModule(MainActivity.java:147)
    at com.example.pytorch_app.MainActivity.lambda$runInference$1$com-example-pytorch_app-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:131)
    at com.example.pytorch_app.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 

How to solve the problem: undefined method?
